# select s.no with the select statement in procedure

Tags: mysql

i am having a hard time to generate the s.no with the select statement in stored procedure. can anyone please tell me how can i increase the value of variable for each row

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_select_invoice_pdf`(IN `cus_ivc_id` INT(11))
    NO SQL
BEGIN
DECLARE a INT(11);
set a=0;
SELECT
a:=a+1 as 'S.No',
ci.`order_id` as 'Order ID',
cp.`date` as 'Date',
cp.`product_name` as 'Design name',
(`customer_invoice`.`amount`-`customer_invoice`.`discount`) as 'Amount'

from `customer_invoice` ci

LEFT JOIN `customer_product` cp on cp.`customer_product_id` = 
ci.`customer_product_id`
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

> Error: MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the
>   right syntax to use near ':=a+1 as 'S.No', ci.`order_id` as 'Order
>   ID', cp' at line 5

however the below is working fine for me but can't figure out how to do it in stored procedure. your help will be appreciated.

```
set @a:=0;
SELECT
@a:=@a+1 as 'S.No',
ci.`order_id` as 'Order ID',
cp.`date` as 'Date',
cp.`product_name` as 'Design name',
(`customer_invoice`.`amount`-`customer_invoice`.`discount`) as 'Amount'

from `customer_invoice` ci

LEFT JOIN `customer_product` cp on cp.`customer_product_id` = 
ci.`customer_product_id`;
```

Comment: Why did you decide not to use @a in the procedure?

Comment: i tried to declare the variablefirst that's why

Comment: why can't we use the declared variable in this scenario?